# BASH Case statement, syntax error (unexpected end of file)

Tags: bash, syntax, case

I keep getting a syntax error (unexpected end of file). The syntax looks good to me but something is obviously wrong here. I was hoping someone from the outside might be able to provide from insight.

```
read -p "Create default hosts file?: " yn

       case $yn in
        [Yy] )  echo "Creating default hosts file"
            sleep 1
            cat <<-EOF1 > /etc/hosts
               Do not remove the following line, or various programs that  require network functionality will fail.
               127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost

               192.168.1.1      test01
               192.168.1.2      test02
               192.168.1.3      test03
               EOF1
                if [ "$(wc -m /etc/hosts)" == "215 /etc/hosts" ] ; then
               echo -e "Default Hosts file\e[1;32m COMPLETE \e[0m"     
            else
               echo -e "Default hosts file\e[1;31m FAILED \e[0m"
               sleep 1
               echo "Please correct before continuing"
               echo "EXITING..."
               sleep 1
               exit
            fi;;
        [Nn] )  echo 'Searching "/etc/hosts" for test03 entry'
            sleep 1
            grep "test03" /etc/hosts >/dev/null
            if [ "$?" -eq 0 ] ; then
               echo "Entry found!"
               echo "Setup Continuing..."
            else
               echo '"test03" entry not found'
               sleep 1
               echo "Please correct before continuing"
               sleep 1
               echo "EXITING..."
               sleep 1
               exit
            fi;;
         *   )  echo "Please answer [Yy] or [Nn].";;
       esac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end-of here document marker should be the first thing on a line except for tab characters:

```
cat <<-EOF1 > /etc/hosts
           Do not remove the following line, or various programs that  require network functionality will fail.
           127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost

           192.168.1.1      test01
           192.168.1.2      test02
           192.168.1.3      test03
EOF1
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be the first thing -- it can also have literal tab characters (NOT SPACES) before it, being `<<-` rather than `<<`; that said, given how hard it is to distinguish between kinds of whitespace, this is indeed not a best practice to rely on.

Comment: Thank you! The EOF1 ending the end-of here document had a few spaces after the tab. I tried to line it up with the top marker...